# OptaPlanner HashCode violation: the hashCode of tabu (entity) probably changed since it was inserted in the tabu Map or Set

Tags: optaplanner

I'm getting a HashCode violation.  The solver works for about a minute, and then results in this error.  The entity is Vehicle.  Using default constructor. No custom moves.  All scoring rules are drools.

Any ideas are appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: HashCode violation: the hashCode of tabu (Vehicle>10) probably changed since it was inserted in the tabu Map or Set.
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.acceptor.tabu.AbstractTabuAcceptor.adjustTabuList(AbstractTabuAcceptor.java:108)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.acceptor.tabu.AbstractTabuAcceptor.stepEnded(AbstractTabuAcceptor.java:98)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.stepEnded(LocalSearchDecider.java:159)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchSolverPhase.stepEnded(DefaultLocalSearchSolverPhase.java:127)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchSolverPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchSolverPhase.java:83)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.runSolverPhases(DefaultSolver.java:190)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:155)
at org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.app.CloudBalancingHelloWorld.main(CloudBalancingHelloWorld.java:56)
```

Comment: If `tabu` is a Java class: which members affect the hashCode method and is any of these members modified in a rule?

Comment: None of the rules modify any of the facts.  All of the rules are scoring rules that just apply relationships between the facts to derive a score.

Comment: Just a thought: This optaplanner mailing list thread (http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/rules-users/2014-March/035180.html) might help you.

Comment: I noticed that the selected move count increased significantly just before the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Any idea what class's toString() would return "Vehicle>10"? That class's hashCode() changed while it was used a key in a Map.

There are 2 solutions:

- Use a stable hashCode(), for example based on a database key. The default Object.hashCode() is also fine (memory id). Based on a business key that never changes, such as username is fine too. Of course, any change on hashCode() must also be reflected in equals().
- Don't use Tabu Search, use Late Acceptance.

Comment: [Error message improved for 6.3.0.Beta2](http://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/commit/ca28a55a9)